# How/where to leave a comment for a user with only a deleted answer?

Tags: discussion, comments

I'd like to leave a message for the author of this [deleted answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/32723/12102) encouraging them to undelete.

I left the following [comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/32721/where-is-the-antenna-farm-from-which-this-soyuz-launch-photo-was-taken#comment99989_32721) below my question [Where is the “antenna farm” from which this Soyuz launch photo was taken?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32721/12102):

> @QiLinXue it's okay if your answer has some amount overlap with the other answer, I don't think it's necessary to delete it after you obviously put some work into it. You also have new information and links that would be interesting to others Consider undeleting? It's also a good way to pick up your first few reputation points. fyi users with rep above 10,000 can still see deleted answers anyway. Thanks, and Welcome to Space!

but I don't know if authors of deleted answers still receive flags for @comments under questions.

I can't post a comment on the deleted answer itself of course.

Since they don't have any other posts, and have not been in chat is there any other way to suggest the undelete?

In this question I am asking about how the various features of the SE interface work, not "Should I encourage someone to undelete..."

Comment: BTW, right now the "10k" privileges are actually granted at 2k, and will be until beta ends.

Comment: @NathanTuggy good to know, thanks! Was that just one random change or is it part of a group of changes?

Comment: All privileges over 250 rep are granted at lower levels; [the full privilege level comparison is laid out on the mother meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared/160292#160292).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to notify the user. The best you can hope for is that they drop by and happen to see your comment. Of course, if they do drop by in chat, you can try to catch them then.