# How to view deleted users posts?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers, user-accounts

While looking up reaction wheel info I came across this question: [Optimal placement of 4 reaction wheels?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/8/optimal-placement-of-4-reaction-wheels?rq=1) and would like to see if there is more from the user who is now gone?

Comment: I'm guessing no. Even if a user is still active (which that one doesn't seem to be after so many years), if they don't have a post or a comment, you can't comment to them [How/where to leave a comment for a user with only a deleted answer?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1123/12102)

Comment: ...but I [might be wrong](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1245/12102)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stack Exchange Data Explorer might at least help; you can search posts by the deleted owner's display name.

[Posts by deleted owner's display name](https://data.stackexchange.com/space/query/1025906/posts-by-deleted-owners-display-name?DisplayName=user29)

```
SELECT Id AS [Post Link], Score, Body
FROM Posts
WHERE PostTypeId <=2 AND OwnerUserId IS NULL AND OwnerDisplayName = '##DisplayName##'
ORDER BY CreationDate ASC
```

(not tested thoroughly, *might be buggy*)

Comment: `+1` nice! I've heard of [six-sigma black belt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_Sigma), I wonder if there is a "SEDE black belt" badge?